# Can you change the DirectoryIndex of specific directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directoryindex

I know that you can use `DirectoryIndex example.html` in .htaccess, but what I need is to change the index for specific directories, like so:

```
DirectoryIndex /ex/index_file.html
```

or

```
DirectoryIndex /ex2/index_file2.html
```

Is there a way that you can accomplish this? I don't want to rename the file I'm trying to do this for to index.html because that's not what it is. You are required to login first, and if you're not it will redirect you; but I think that looks sloppy.

Comment: I mean like, say I have 2 separate directories. `dir1` and `dir2`. For `dir1` I want the DirectoryIndex to be `example.html` and for `dir2` I want the DirectoryIndex to be `another_example.html`. Does that help?

Comment: Oh got it I guess you can read the answer down there, I guess it should solve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an .htaccess in each directory that you want a different directory index in. The .htaccess in the `ex` directory should contain:

```
DirectoryIndex index_file.html
```

But the on in `ex2` should contain:

```
DirectoryIndex index_file2.html
```

You can also use [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) in the .htaccess in your web root as long as you are allowed to override this:

```
<Directory ex>
   DirectoryIndex index_file.html
</Directory>

<Directory ex2>
    DirectoryIndex index_file2.html
</Directory>
```

Comment: This solved my question. :) I thought you might be able to do that, I guess I should've tried before posting the questions; oh well. Thanks for the help!